# Use Tomcat's "endorsed" directory for JDBC implementation jar?

Tags: tomcat

Our vendor recommends to place the MySQL JDBC jar into the Tomcat 6 "$CATALINA_HOME/endorsed" directory.

It is unclear to me what the purpose of that recommendation is.

The [Classloader Howto](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) for Tomcat 6 states the following about the "endorsed" mechanism:

> Java supports a mechanism called the "Endorsed Standards Override
>   Mechanism" to allow replacement of APIs created outside of the JCP
>   (i.e. DOM and SAX from W3C). It can also be used to update the XML
>   parser implementation. For more information, see:
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/standards/index.html.
>
> Tomcat utilizes this mechanism by including the system property
>   setting -Djava.endorsed.dirs=$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS in the command line
>   that starts the container. The default value of this option is
>   $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed. This endorsed directory is not created by
>   default.

Thus, the "$CATALINA_HOME/endorsed" directory, if created and if activated on the command line, can be used to override implementations of APIs that come with the JDK. But the JDK does not come with a default implementation for JDBC.

If one wanted to load the MySQL JDBC implementation into a classloader "higher than a webapp classloader", in this case, the "common" classloader:

[image: Tomcat 6 classloader hierarchy]

...one would put it into "$CATALINA_HOME/lib" or "$CATALINA_BASE/lib" as described in the Classloader Howto.

Is my vendor recommending Bad Practices?

**Note to self**

In Tomcat 5 the [Classloader hierarchy](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html) was as follows:

[image: Tomcat 5 classloader hierarchy]

Thank God for simplifications!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes he is.

The purpose of that recommendation is to make the JAR available server wide and maybe to be loaded before everything in the common directory, because the hierarchy presented also dictates what is loaded first.